# Show that $A+B=AB+BA$ iff $\text{Tr}(A)=\text{Tr}(B)=\text{Tr}(AB)=1$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

We have $A,B$ $(2×2)$ matrices with complex entries. We know $AB≠BA$. Show that $A+B=AB+BA$ if and only if $\text{Tr}(A)=\text{Tr}(B)=\text{Tr}(AB)=1$.

I tried writing $A=X+Y$ and $B=X-Y$ so we can get $X=X^{2}-Y^{2}$ but from here I know what to do.

Comment: How do you get $X = X^2 - Y^2$?

Comment: If we solve the first subproblem we get from $A+B=AB+BA$ to $X=X^{2}-Y^{2}$ because $A+B=X+Y+X-Y=2X$ and $AB+BA=X^{2}-XY-Y^{2}+X^{2}+XY-YX-Y^{2}=2(X^{2}-Y^{2})$

Comment: It's not necessary that $AB\neq BA$. For instance, the matrices $A=\text{diag}(t,1-t)$, $B=\text{diag}(1-t,t)/(1-2t)$ commute and satisfy both sides of the biconditional for any $0<t<1$.

Comment: What that diag means?

Comment: A diagonal matrix with those matrix elements on the diagonal.

Comment: @Semiclassical In your example, isn't $\operatorname{tr}(B) = \frac{(1-t)+t}{1-2t} = \frac{1}{1 - 2t} \neq 1$?

Comment: @vtand you’re right. I think it should have been $-t$ in the second entry.

Comment: @Semiclassical That wouldn't work either, because then $$AB = \frac{1}{1-2t}\begin{pmatrix}t & 0 \\ 0 & 1-t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1-t & 0 \\ 0 & -t\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{1-2t}\begin{pmatrix}t(1-t) & 0 \\ 0 &-t(1-t)\end{pmatrix}$$ and thus $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S=A+B$. Define $\tau_s=\operatorname{tr}(S),\,\delta_s=\det(S)$ and define $\tau_a,\tau_b,\delta_a,\delta_b$ analogously. Then
$$
\begin{align}
&AB+BA-(A+B)\\
&=S^2-(A^2+B^2)-S\\
&=(S^2-S)-A^2-B^2\\
&=(\tau_s-1)S-\delta_sI-(\tau_aA-\delta_aI)-(\tau_b B-\delta_bI)\\
&=(\tau_b-1)A+(\tau_a-1)B+(\delta_a+\delta_b-\delta_s)I.\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
$$
Now suppose $AB+BA=A+B$, so that the sum on line $(1)$ is zero. If one of $\tau_b-1$ and $\tau_a-1$ is nonzero, then one of $A$ and $B$ is a linear combination of the other and the identity matrix, but this is impossible because $A$ and $B$ by assumption do not commute. Hence we must have $\tau_a=\tau_b=1$ and $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(AB+BA)=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(A+B)=1$.

Conversely, if $\tau_a=\tau_b=\operatorname{tr}(AB)=1$, then $AB+BA-(A+B)=(\delta_a+\delta_b-\delta_s)I$, by $(1)$.
Since the LHS is traceless, the RHS, which is a scalar multiple of $I$, must be zero. Therefore $AB+BA=A+B$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But how did you get the second relation ?

Comment: @StefanSolomon What second relation?